# Arrow keys not working as expected

Tags: keyboard, finder, monterey, web-browser

The system is Monterey 12.5.1 and Mac Mini 2018

There are two occurance of the problem. One of them while using Finder. When I press space bar and preview files, I am supposed to switch between files with up and down key. If I press down key Help from menu bar opens and focuses on search. The second one occurs in browsers (Chrome, Safari, and Opera). When I start to type the address, the browser lists corresponding addresses. I used to select the address I wish via up and down keys. Yet, it opens Help from menu bar and focuses on search too. Is there any solution for that?

[Screen capture](https://streamable.com/y6fksl)

Comment: Check your accessibility preferences to make sure nothing is turned on.

Comment: It looks like availabe options are disabled. 
https://ibb.co/jR6g1nn
https://ibb.co/K7r7QQL
https://ibb.co/n8959YX